# Extracting data from AudioBufferList in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, core-audio, swift3

I'm trying to extract the native [Float] array out of a rendered AudioBufferList where the audio unit's stream is set up for 32-bit floating point. In Swift 1 & 2 I did this:

```
    var monoSamples = [Float]()
    for i in 0..<Int(inNumberFrames) {
        withUnsafePointer(to: &bufferList.mBuffers.mData, {
            let ptr = $0
            let newPtr = ptr + i
            let sample = unsafeBitCast(newPtr.pointee, to: Float.self)
            monoSamples.append(sample)
        })
    }
```

Undoubtedly not the fastest method, but it worked. In Swift 3 this compiles without error but at runtime I get a crash:

> fatal error: can't unsafeBitCast between types of different sizes

That's a bit surprising; Swift's Float is 32-bit and the stream's data is 32-bit.

What I'd like to do is simply:

```
    withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &bufferList.mBuffers.mData, {
        let monoSamples = [Float](UnsafeBufferPointer(start: $0, count:Int(inNumberFrames)))
    })
```

But there I get a compile error:

> Expression type '[Float]' is ambiguous without more context

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Here's a gist that compiles (well, _should_ compile) in a Swift Playground: gist.github.com/anonymous/4d55cd1ec55a5f71246780f4819c94b3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you un-converted your code to Swift 2, it does not work. You may have modified too much when converting your code to Swift 3.

Try this:

```
var monoSamples = [Float]()
let ptr = bufferList.mBuffers.mData?.assumingMemoryBound(to: Float.self)
monoSamples.append(contentsOf: UnsafeBufferPointer(start: ptr, count: Int(inNumberFrames)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be?

Yeah you are correct, You have to input your `$0` as `UnsafePointer`. Choose any type of `UnsafePointer` initializer and pass that value here, for the explanation purpose I have used `bitPattern` here.

```
UnsafeBufferPointer<Float>(start: UnsafePointer(bitPattern: i), count: Int(inNumberFrames))
```

Comment: No love. Now the error is: "Expression type 'UnsafeBufferPointer<Float>' is ambiguous without more context"

Comment: Thanks but I'm still confused. We're inside a withUnsafeMutablePointer closure here, yes? Where does the $0 go? `monoSamples = [Float](UnsafeBufferPointer<Float>(start: UnsafePointer($0), count:Int(inNumberFrames)))` produces yet another error.

Comment: Here's a gist that compiles (well, _should_ compile) in a Swift Playground: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4d55cd1ec55a5f71246780f4819c94b3